# How to Skip One Bullet in ITEMIZE?

Tags: itemize

As aforementioned, I wonder whether I can skip one bullet during `itemize`. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2\\Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Though the code doesn't put the bullet in front of `Item 3`, this seems to be an incorrect solution as just uses `\\`. Can I just remove one particular bullet in `itemize`?

Comment: while the answer does what you ask, I wonder how the reader is supposed to know it is a new item? If it is a linebreak in an existing item, `\\ ` is better markup than `\item[]` or if it is a new paragraph in an existing item then a blank line should be used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- unfortunately, your markup here of `\\ ` didn't work quite correctly.  (Your comment arrived just as I was about to comment on the possible relevance of a paragraph break.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'd fixed the `\\ ` :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item[] Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The empty optional argument of `\item` command will do the trick.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

You could use an unlabeled item, but the reader has no visual clue that it is a new item 
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item[] Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}

You use a forced linebreak in an existing item
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2\\
      Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}

You use a second paragraph in an existing item
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2

      Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}

These three markups encode three different sentence structures so only
you can say which you need with your real text.
\end{document}
```